# The relations between quantum affine algebras and Yangians

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

Drinfeld had said that quantum loop algebras can degenerate into Yangians.But i can not find any proof about that .Can anyone give me some reference about this question.

Comment: See Chapter 12 in Chari and Pressley's book "A guide to quantum groups".

Answer (score 5):

A great very recent paper on the subject is [Yangians and quantum affine algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3687) by Gautam and Toledano-Laredo, where a stronger (and unexpected) form of Drinfeld's result is proved (and there are references to older works of course).

Answer (score 2):

A recent paper give a complete proof:

http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~nguay/NGuayqlooptoYang.pdf